# Dot notation vs square brackets and casting in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Which of the following is best practice in Objective-C?

```
UITableView* view = (UITableView*) [self view];
[view setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[view release];
```

vs.

```
((UITableView*) self.view).separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Or is there a better way of writing this? `self.view` is a `UIView*`.

I'm asking both because I have a weird looking cast (maybe there's a better way?) and because of the following text from the official documentation, which hints that it's more than just a matter of style or personal preference:

> A further advantage is that the compiler can signal an error when it detects an attempt to write to a read-only declared property. If you instead use square bracket syntax for accessing variables, the compiler—at best—generates only an undeclared method warning that you invoked a nonexistent setter method, and the code fails at runtime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well.... dot notation compiles down to square brackets in the end, but it is down to personal preference. I personally avoid dot notation unless I am setting / accessing a scalar type, it is too easy to look at the following for instance...

```
view.step = 2.0;
```

... and not know where step is a scalar property, or has a setter method etc. I prefer to be explicit and would use...

```
[view setStep:2.0];
```

But again personal preference I guess.

Comment: I'm also asking because of the quoted documentation (updated question to add quote).

Comment: Yeah, there are pros to using it, however it is my personal preference not to. I run an iOS development firm and none of my guys use dot notation unless it is a scalar property, but then again, that is most likely due to my preference!

Comment: To add to that, bottom line is this... if you prefer it and you find it easier (with compiler checking) then use it, that's what its there for! :)

Comment: After reading the article I get the impression that its more important to name your methods and properties non-ambiguously than to not use or use dot notation. Most of his examples would be cleared up easily if  named better. For example, [obj value] and [obj value] look the same, but one could just be getting an instance variable and one could be a method doing who-knows-what, yet its that type of vagueness that he criticizes dot notation for. Write your code clearly, and it shouldn't end up mattering what you use.

Comment: You have picked a very ambiguous example out of a whole article of well made points... ;) I personally stick with square brackets for a lot of the reasons mentioned in the article, despite coming from .NET where dot notation is the norm.

Comment: @Matt I Wholly agree. I think his example is too made up. It's kind of the same argument made against operator overloading: "If people with horrible coding style use it, you may not know what they are doing"! Well, that's the case with most things, really.

Answer (score 3):

2 things

1. You didn't ask that but -  I used to love those "One lines" in the beginning, but after some time when you get back to the code it is less readable.
2. the dot seems more readable to me

I would prefer that -

```
    UITableView* view = (UITableView*)self.view;
    view.setSeparatorColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

But in the end it is a matter of your own preferences.

Comment: I agree with the one line comment, I see this way too often and you end up wading through nested brackets and method calls trying to work out what is going on! Dot notation or not, clean written code is the top priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast within the bracket and save yourself a line or two using this syntax:

```
[(UITableView*) self.view setSeparatorColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Or `((UITableView *)self.view).separatorColor = [UIColor redColor]`

Comment: @rid yes, that works too. However, multiple parentheses can get confusing.