# storing instance reference in singleton in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

Let's say I have 2 classes, A and B. A is a singleton. I declare A in B, so I can access the singletons vars in methods in B.

B then creates an instance of another class, say class C.

C Then creates an instance of another class, say class D.

What I need to do is run a method in the instance of class B, from class D, and that's what is driving me nuts.

My first thought was to put a reference to the instance of class b, in my singleton (class A), something like...

```
sharedInstance.classBReference = self;
```

..and then declare the singleton in Class D, and then use something like this in class D instance...

```
[sharedInstance.classBInstance classBInstanceMethod];
```

But of course as soon as I did..

```
classB *classBReference;
```

In the header of my singleton, it game me the "unknown type" which I read about on here, so instead, I put a

```
@class classB;
```

above the @interface, and then I was able to declare...

```
classB *classBReference;
```

Without an error of unknown type, but in the init method of class B, this...

```
sharedInstance.classBReference = self;
```

Still gives me an error of type

"property classBReference not found on objet of type "class A*" (the singleton) did you mean to access ivar classBReference?"

And I have no idea why it's doing that, what's the solution? or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dots and Arrows

The "dot notation" is a somewhat recent addition to Objective-C and provides a shorthand notation for accessors.  If you have a pointer to an object (or a struct!), you cannot access its instance variables with `.` but only with `->`.

Your line

```
sharedInstance.classBReference = self;
```

is exactly the same as

```
[sharedInstance setClassBReference:self];
```

The problem is that you don't have any such method `-setClassBReference:`.  In order to set the instance variable, you must instead write

```
sharedInstance->classBReference = self;
```

### @protected variables

After switching your line with this one, you may (if you haven't made it `@public`) see the error

> Instance variable '`classBReference`' is private

In this case, you need to alter your `classA` interface so that `classBReference` is declared to be `@public`.  Your list of instance variables in `classA` should look something like

```
@interface classA : NSObject
{
//@protected
//(The @protected keyword is optional when at the beginning of the list; instance
//variables are protected by default, which is why you're needing to declare your
//instance variable classBReference to be @public (since classB is not a subclass
//of classA and consequently cannot access its protected instance variables).
    //....
    //some protected instance variables
    //....
@private
    //....
    //some private instance variables
    //....
@public
    //....
    //some public instance variables
    classB *classBReference;
    //....
@protected
    //....
    //some more protected instance variables
    //Note that @protected is not optional in order to make the instance variables
    //here be protected since they are declared subsequent to the prior @public.
    //....
}
//....
@end
```

### Using @properties

#### The case of classBReference

That being said, it is widely regarded as a better practice to use accessors rather than instance variables in general.  In order to do this, you should add a property to your `classA` interface:

```
@interface classA : NSObject
{
    classB *classBReference;
}
@property classB *classBReference;
@end
```

and synthesize the `classBReference` **property** to access the `classBReference` **instance variable** in `classA`'s implementation as follows:

```
@implementation classB

@synthesize classBReference = classBReference;
```

#### The general set-up

The `@synthesize` is somewhat unclear on account of the fact that we have both an instance variable and a property with the same name.  Some clarification is in order.  In general, in a class's ("`MyObject`" in this example) `@interface` one declares an instance variable ("`myVariable`" in this example) and a property ("`myProperty`" in this example).

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    SomeObject *myVariable;
}
@property SomeObject *myProperty;
@end
```

In the class's `@implementation` one has the line

```
@synthesize myProperty = myVariable.
```

The result of this code is that, given an instance

```
MyObject *object = //...
```

of the class, one is able to write

```
SomeObject *someObject = //...
[object setMyProperty:someObject];
```

and

```
SomeObject *someOtherObject = [object myProperty];
```

The result of calling `-setMyProperty:` on the instance of `MyObject` is that `myVariable` is set equal to the argument passed into the method--in this case `someObject`.  Similarly, the result of calling `-myProperty` on the instance of `MyObject` is that `myVariable` is returned.

#### What does it get us?

Without the `@property` and `@synthesize` directives, one would have to declare the methods

```
- (void)setMyProperty:(SomeObject *)myProperty;
- (SomeObject *)myProperty;
```

manually and define them manually as well:

```
- (void)setMyProperty:(SomeObject *)myProperty
{
    myVariable = myProperty;
}

- (SomeObject *)myProperty
{
    return myVariable;
}
```

The `@property` and `@synthesize` provide some abridgment to this code.  The amount of code that is generated for you becomes even more beneficial when you use various of the [property attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2).

**Note**: There is [more to say](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) about the `@property` and `@synthesize` directives.  For a start, not only can you write `@synthesize myProperty;` omitting the variable name, you can omit the synthesizing of `myProperty` entirely, and the variable names that are used automatically are different from one another in these two cases.

### A Bit More on Dot Notation

The dot notation from your question provides another layer of abbreviation.  Rather than having to write

```
[object setMyProperty:someObject];
```

you are now able to write

```
object.myProperty = someObject;
```

Similarly, rather than having to write

```
SomeObject *someOtherObject = [object myProperty];
```

you are now able to write

```
SomeObject *someOtherObject = object.myProperty;
```

It is important to note that this is just **just notation**.  Though it "kinda looks like" we're doing simple assignment when we "set `object.myProperty` equal to `someObject`", that is *not* the case.  In particular, when we execute the line

```
object.myProperty = someObject;
```

the method

```
- (void)setMyProperty:(SomeObject *)someObject
```

is executed.  For this reason, [dot](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/83-83/) [notation](http://qualitycoding.org/dot-notation/) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292753/dot-notation-vs-square-brackets-and-casting-in-objective-c) [a](http://fernmac.blogspot.com/2012/04/objective-c-dot-notation-or-message.html) [subject](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=160) [of](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2227) [some](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/08/dot-notation-controversy.html) [contention](http://jrfom.com/2010/06/16/objective-c-dot-notation/).  It is a convenience, but it is important to keep in mind what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the answer. You should define `classBReference` as property or use `classBReference` as ivar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'd be less confused by avoiding the global variable (aka singleton).  Give the `C` a reference to the `B` when the `B` creates the `C`.  Give the `D` a reference to the `B` when the `C` creates the `D`.

If you need to avoid a retain cycle, make the back-references to the `B` either `weak` (if your deployment target is at least iOS 5.0) or `unsafe_unretained` (if your deployment target is earlier than iOS 5.0).