# Error "Property setVariableName not found" using dot notation to set property

Tags: objective-c, syntax, accessor, declared-property

I've just started learning Objective-C and I'm not sure when to use dot notation vs. square brackets. I know a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292753/dot-notation-vs-square-brackets-and-casting-in-objective-c) but I'm still not really understanding the difference. I've read that `[myObject doSomething]` and `myObject.doSomething` are equivalent. What I'm not sure about though is that when I use `@property` to generate a method it automatically generates a setter method that I can only use with square brackets.

```
// MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property int number;
```

```
// main.m
MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[object setNumber:3];
object.setNumber = 4; // Property 'setNumber' not found
```

Why am I getting error messages when I write `object.setNumber = 4` and why can I only use square brackets for this?

Comment: use `object.number = 4`

Comment: The equivalent statement with dot notation is object.number = 4, not object.setNumber = 4. Dot notation uses the name of the property itself, not the name of the setter.

Comment: You can use the dot notation whenever you have a method that takes 0 or 1 parameters. The problem with your code is (why you get the warning) that you must *not* use `set` in dot notation. Why is that? The compiler generates a normal method call from dot notation. So if you write `object.number = 4;` the compiler generates `[object setNumber:4];`. That's why it doesn't work when you write `object.setNumber = 4;` because the compiler generates `[object setSetNumber:4];` and that method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because the property is called `number` not setNumber. It is common in OOP languages to create methods that access an object's data using "setters" and "getters." A property in Objective-C 2.0 synthesizes this process and automatically generates the setters and getters. If you go into MyClass.m and enter `- setN` you will see setNumber suggested by Xcode. That is because you can implement your setters and getters yourself to customize their behavior, or leave the default behavior of simply setting a value or getting a value.

Additionally, properties automatically generate the variable declaration as `_variableName` For instance, the default behavior of your property would be:

```
- (void) setNumber:(int)number {
    _number = number
}

- (int) getNumber {
    return _number;
}
```

Determining whether you should use one over the other really comes down to consistency. To ensure consistency in teams, a Style Guide should be in place. Take the [NY Times](https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide) for instance. They restrict dot notation strictly to Properties and brackets for non-property methods (i.e. setters and getters).

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing methods and properties.

When you make a property, yes it creates a setter method called setVARIABLE.

The only way to call a method is with the bracket notation. IE `[object setNumber:3];` (Unless you have 0, or 1 parameters, thanks HAS)

What you want to do is use the property name, not the setter (or getter) method.

```
[object number];
```

That will return the value of number. You can't read properties when accessing them through bracket notation, it's only readonly (only accessing the get function).

```
object.number = 3;
```

That's how you would set the property number using dot notation.

When you wrote `object.setNumber = 3;` you were treating setNumber like a property, which it's not, it's a method.

To recap

1. methods are only usable by bracket notation, not dot notation `[object setNumber:3];` (Unless you have 0, or 1 parameters)
2. you can only read a property when accessing it through bracket notation `[object number]; //returns the value of number`
3. you can read and write a property when using it through dot notation `object.number = 3;`

Comment: Your "variable" terminology is off. `[object number]` is a message send just like `[object doThatThingYouDo]`. It's not "reading a variable"; a method is being run; its return value may be the value of an instance variable, but that's not inherent. Neither is `object.number` direct access of a variable. It's syntactic sugar for, again, (a message send that results in) a method call. "The only way to call a method is with the bracket notation. IE `[object setNumber:3];`" is thus not correct.

Comment: Sorry for lack of correct terminology. I updated my answer to include correct terminology.